# use hide/show in jquery each

Tags: jquery, delay, show, each, slide

this code dont works, how i resolve it ?

i hide everything .. after this, i show one by one in a delay of 7 seconds..

but everything is showed, i dont understand why

```
$(function()    {
    texts = $('.text-block');
    slide = $('#slideshow');


    // hide everything
    texts.each(function()   {
       $(this).hide(); 
    });

    // show it once by once
    jQuery.each(texts, function()   {
       $(this).show(300);
       $(this).delay(7000);
       $(this).hide(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need to use .each,

```
texts = $('.text-block');
texts.hide(); // hides all matched elements
```

As far as showings each one by one, the delay doesn't stop the execution of the entire js thread, that would be blocking and bad and make your application seem very unresponsive.. To show them one by one you'd have to write it differently

Maybe a recursive function that you pass the next element in after the delay, using a promise to know when the animation and delay is complete?

like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/SbYTL/1/

```
function ShowItems(items, delay) {
    $(items[0]).fadeIn(300)
        .delay(delay)
        .fadeOut(300)
        .promise()
        .done(function() {
            items.splice(0, 1);
            if (items.length > 0)
            {
                ShowItems(items, delay);    
            }            
    });       
}

var items = $(".text-block").hide();  
ShowItems(items, 7000);
```

Comment: updated jsfiddle example to exactly match your problem, with example usage.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's delaying from the same point, if you put the delay in the right place.

```
$(function()    {
    texts = $('.text-block');
    slide = $('#slideshow');


    // hide everything
    texts.hide(); 

    // show it once by once
    texts.each( function(index)   {
       $(this).delay(7000 * index).show(300);
    });
});
```

Do you want to hide it a second time after you show it? I removed that, since it would just show then hide.

Shortened version:

```
$(function() {
    $('.text-block').each(function(index){
        $(this).hide().delay(7000 * index).show(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: index starts from 0, may be you need (index+1) inside delay and `texts.hide()` should hide everything instead of `.each`

Comment: True, depending on if you want to delay the first one 7seconds or not.

Comment: mm true.. Good Answer +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out using [`.throttle`](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) instead.

Comment: not a bad idea, seems like it might be difficult to use with foreach though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.text-block').hide().each(function(item, index) {
         $(item).delay(7000*index).show(300, function() {
             $(this).delay(7000).hide(300);
         });
    });
});
```